# Inserting and updating customer data into MYOB cloud using PHP?

Tags: php, myob

I'm new to **MYOB** development. 
 I need to insert customer data using cloud auth. I'm using php. I want sample code for inserting and updating data.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you are referring to MYOB desktop application)

You need to install MYOB application and the ODBC on windows then using the ODBC to insert the records..

another way is to export a file that the user need to download and import to MYOB.

Comment: This only applies to AccountRight V19 which uses ODBC. AccountRight Live is in the cloud and has a REST-based API and uses OAuth to control access to company files hosted in the cloud.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. Hence my first line in the answer :)

Comment: AccountRight Live can also be desktop which is different to AccountRight v19 and hence my clarification

Comment: I use AccountRight Live V2 with php , I finallly able to sent data to MYOB. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned which MYOB product you are trying to access.

The first place I would start is the [developer portal](http://developer.myob.com/) which details all the endpoints and data structures.  You should also consider joining the developer program as this will give you access to the forums and Sample Ledgers that you can test your application against.

There are a number of [samples on github](https://github.com/MYOB-Technology) of which there is a [PHP sample for AccountRight](https://github.com/MYOB-Technology/AccountRight_ContactSample_PHP) of which the OAuth cycle is the same regardless of the product.

Comment: I use AccountRight Live V2 with php , I finallly able to sent data to MYOB. Thanks for the help